# Chrome: removeEventListener doesn't remove listener returned by getEventListeners

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I'm trying to remove an event listener based on its function definition in the Chrome console, but it doesn't want to go away.

```js
getEventListeners(window).scroll.forEach(({listener}) => {
    if (listener.toString().contains('scrollTo')) {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', listener) || console.log('not removed')
    }
})
```

The behaviour seems to indicate that `listener` isn't the same instance of the event handler, in which case this will never work.

Am I doing something wrong though, and if yes, what?

Comment: The `listener` is definitely the same function that was passed in. Make sure you match the `useCapture` flag of the listener when removing it. Where are you actually running this code? `getEventListeners()` can only be run manually from the DevTools console. Also, `removeEventListener()` always returns `undefined`, regardless if it was successful or not, so your `console.log()` will run in any case.

Comment: @Lennholm I am running that in the DevTools. Some website has a load of stuff to prevent me from scrolling until I do what their banner says: css overflow stuff, scroll event handler... I wanted to remove the scroll event handler with this code, instead of removing it with my mouse from the window object, but no chance. I know it doesn't work because the window object still shows it and it still operates. I've tried with both values for `useCapture`.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't vote on this answer. I had to add this comment as an answer, considering SO haven't had implemented a decent code markdown in the comments so far...

I have a similar situation using latest Google Chrome and its DevTools, where only 1 specific event listener is being removed (out of 2 existing). No matter what I try, the other one doesn't want to be removed. Here is my code:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('#image')].forEach(e => {
    var l = getEventListeners(e);
    console.log(l);
    if (l.contextmenu) {
        l.contextmenu.forEach(m => {
            console.log(m);
            e.removeEventListener(m.type, m.listener, m.useCapture);
        });
    });
```

and here is the result of it:
[image]

When I run this same code the second time, I still get 1 specific stubborn event listener, which just doesn't want to go... Does anyone know what's going on?